# Convert C# DateTime object to libpcap capture file timestamp

Tags: c#, datetime, packet-sniffers

I am stuck in converting a DateTime object to a timestamp for the libpcap capture file format (is also used by wireshark, [file format definitiom](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat)) in C#. The timestamp I can't manage to convert my object to is the Timestamp in the packet (record) header (guint32 ts_sec and guint32 ts_usec).

Comment: It looks like these timestamps are just the number of seconds as an uint32 and microseconds as an uint32. At a guess, these are measured from the start of the UNIX Epoch (January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC)

Comment: They are - I just posted code to do the conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
DateTime dateToConvert = DateTime.Now;
DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan diff = date - origin;

// Seconds since 1970
uint ts_sec = Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
// Microsecond offset
uint ts_usec = 1000000 * (diff.TotalSeconds - ts_sec);
```

Comment: Nice answer. Here same in integer arithmetic using .Ticks member.
`TimeSpan ts = YourDateTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
UInt32 ts_sec = (UInt32)(ts.Ticks / 10000000);
UInt32 ts_usec = (UInt32)((ts.Ticks / 10) % 1000000);`

Answer (score 0):

It is best to convert the Unix Epoch and your dateToConvert to UTC before any manipulation.  There is a constructor for DateTime that takes a DateTimeKind for constructing the UnixEpoch, and there is a ToUniversalTime() method for the dateToConvert.  If you always want Now, there is a handy DateTime.UtcNow property that takes care of that for you.  The code as written shouldn't have any problems, but if you make this a function, a UTC date could be passed and working with a UTC target date and a local Unix Epoch would certainly not give the right results unless you are in GMT and not on summer time.